# How to invoke function by reference

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I rendered a list of modal/popups and control them by using state.

```
renderGenericOKModal({ title, message, visibleStateVar }) {
    return (
      <PromptModal
        alertTitle={title}
        alertMessage={message}
        isVisible={this.state[visibleStateVar]}
        onRightButtonPress={() =>
          this.setState({ [visibleStateVar]: false });
        }
        rightButtonLabel={strings.labelOK}
      />
    );
  }
```

I see some comments on medium saying that the code above is not optimized because it creates a lot of unnecessarily similar function for `onRightButtonPress`. So I tried to do something as below but not sure if it actually make any differences?

```
genericOKButtonOnPress = ({ visibleStateVar }) => {
  this.setState({ [visibleStateVar]: false });
};

onRightButtonPress={() =>
  this.genericOKButtonOnPress({ visibleStateVar })
}
```

But the code above is still creating each individual anonymous function object which looks the same as my original code right?

**UPDATES:**

```
onRightButtonPress={this.genericOKButtonOnPress.bind(null, {
  visibleStateVar
})}
```

Using `bind` should be beneficial for my case right?

Comment: `bind` creates another function, just like `onRightButtonPress={() =>
          this.setState({ [visibleStateVar]: false });
        }` creates another function, though

Answer (score 0):

Define the `onRightButtonPress` using [`arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) without anonymous function.

```
onRightButtonPress = () => this.genericOKButtonOnPress({ visibleStateVar }) //inline
```

or

```
onRightButtonPress = () => {
  this.genericOKButtonOnPress({ visibleStateVar })
} //using block
```

**PromptModal** should be

```
<PromptModal
  alertTitle={title}
  alertMessage={message}
  isVisible={this.state[visibleStateVar]}
  onRightButtonPress=this.onRightButtonPress
  rightButtonLabel={strings.labelOK}
/>
```

Comment: But how to pass the variable `visibleStateVar` over?

Comment: `visibleStateVar` was passed into `renderGenericOKModal` and how should I pass over to `this.onRightButtonPress`?

Comment: @Isaac you setting it on `state.this.setState({ [visibleStateVar]: false });`

Comment: I dont get it, `onRightButtonPress` has no access to `visibleStateVar`